# Javascript: for-loop not working

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, closures, anonymous

I have this code right here.. where the variable *num* is the dimension of a n by n square table. The objective is to enter a number and create a table with the number as the dimension.

I got this code but it doesn't go through the 2 layers of for-loops. After the code execution, the string *change_text* just becomes: `<table></table>`

```
    change_text = "<table>";

    for (var i; i<num; i++) {
        change_text = change_text + "<tr>";
        for (var j; j<num; j++) {
            change_text = change_text + "<td> asdf </td>";

            //code for blue cells
        }
        change_text = change_text + "</tr>";
    }


    change_text = change_text+ "</table>"
```

Comment: For reference, you can simply do `change_text += "new text";` instead of `change_text = change_text + "new text";`

Answer (score 8):

You need to initialize your iterators:

```
for(var i = 0; i < num; i++)
```

Answer (score 4):

Ohhh also I noticed that num isn't defined specifically. Wherever you're getting num from make sure to use parseInt if it could have possibly been passed as a string.`num = parseInt(num);`

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the starting value for your loops:

```
change_text = "<table>";

    for (var i = 0; i<num; i++) {
        change_text = change_text + "<tr>";
        for (var j = 0; j<num; j++) {
            change_text = change_text + "<td> asdf </td>";

            //code for blue cells
        }
        change_text = change_text + "</tr>";
    }


    change_text = change_text+ "</table>"
```

At present I would assume `i` and `j` are `undefined` and so the loops won't go anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

you need to initialize i and j...
try this:

```
change_text = "<table>";

for (var i=0; i<num; i++) {
    change_text = change_text + "<tr>";
    for (var j=0; j<num; j++) {
        change_text = change_text + "<td> asdf </td>";

        //code for blue cells
    }
    change_text = change_text + "</tr>";
}


change_text = change_text+ "</table>"
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize i and j, like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i<num; i++)
```

Answer (score 2):

Not initialized i,make i=0

```
 for (var i=0; i<num; i++) {
       //code
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `i=0`/`j=0` initialisation. You only declared the variables, and `undefined` always yields `false` from numeric comparisons which breaks the loop immediately. So change your code to

```
change_text = "<table>";
for (var i=0; i<num; i++) {
    change_text = change_text + "<tr>";
    for (var j=0; j<num; j++) {
        change_text = change_text + "<td> asdf </td>";
        //code for blue cells
    }
    change_text = change_text + "</tr>";
}
change_text = change_text+ "</table>"
```